# Neo4j Apoc Case When get result summary in java

Tags: java, spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-apoc

Hey I'm currently writing a Java application that accesses NEO4J via Spring Neo4J Driver.
I have a couple of nodes with arrays. No I'm trying to write an cypher Query that deletes an Element from an array of a matched node. If the element was the last one i would love to delete the complete node. To achive this I'm using `apoc.do.when`. You can find a simplified version of my query below.

```
MATCH (n:NODE)  WHERE "Peter" IN n.NAMES
CALL apoc.do.when(size(n.NAMES) > 1, 'SET n.NAMES = [x IN n.NAMES WHERE x <> "Peter"]', 'DETACH DELETE n') YIELD value
RETURN value
```

My query is overall working fine, but I don't get the Result summary back anymore in my Java application.
I'm calling the query the following way:

```
ResultSummary output = driver.session().run(query.withParameters(params)).consume();
```

I know that the query is executed and deleting a node. I validated that by Neo4J browser, but the result summary says:

```
serverInfo=InternalServerInfo{address='localhost:7687', version='Neo4j/3.5.17'}, databaseInfo=InternalDatabaseInfo{name='null'}, queryType=READ_WRITE, counters=null, plan=null, profile=null, notifications=[], resultAvailableAfter=143, resultConsumedAfter=1}
Updates: 0
Delete: 0
```

Therefore i can not validate from my Javacode if the operation was successful. I assume that `apoc.do.when` does not promote the result summary from the query correctly. Is there anyway to fix this or do i need to validate this with a second query?

Comment: apoc procedures do not promote the result summary correctly. You could use plain cypher for this simple operation probably if you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the Cypher query to return a result that indicates whether an update or deletion occurred. For example:

```
MATCH (n:NODE) WHERE "Peter" IN n.NAMES
CALL apoc.do.when(
  size(n.NAMES) > 1,
  'SET n.NAMES = [x IN n.NAMES WHERE x <> "Peter"] RETURN "updated" AS res',
  'DETACH DELETE n RETURN "deleted" AS res') YIELD value
RETURN value.res AS res
```

Then your Java client can iterate through (or stream) the resulting records and count the number of updates and deletions.